# How to reverse a number in Java accepted by user and add both reversed number

Tags: java

I have written a code to reverse a number in java. But its taking only one character/displaying it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class HelloWorld
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
int n,n1, reverse = 0,rev = 0;
System.out.println("Enter the number to reverse");

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.err.println("Please enter first number to reverse : ");
int number = scanner.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter second number to reverse :");
int num = scanner.nextInt();

if( number >0)
{
reverse = reverse * 10;
reverse = reverse + number%10;
number = number/10;

 if(num>0)
  {
    rev = rev * 10;
    rev = rev + num%10;
    num = num/10;
  }

 }
 System.out.println("Reverse of entered number is "+reverse);
 System.out.println("Reverse of entered number is "+rev);
}
}
```

Input1 -65
output displayed - 5
Input2 -34
output displayed - 4

I have to reverse the user accpeted inputs and add the reverse of both boths inputs.

Comment: Use `while` instead of `if` and you are assuming that first number will be longer than second. Do the two reversing operations separately

Comment: @user7 It worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this , as @user7 pointed out, use an while loop , instead of if loop

```
while( number >0)
{
    reverse1 = reverse1 * 10;
    reverse1 = reverse1 + number%10;
    number = number/10;
}
while( number2 >0)
{
    reverse2 = reverse2 * 10;
    reverse2 = reverse2 + num%10;
    num = num/10;
}

System.out.println(reverse1+reverse2);
```

now for multiple Numbers

```
int[] numbers= numbers to be reversed;
reverseSum=0;
for(int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
    reverseSum+= reverse(numbers[i]);
}
...

public int reverse(int number){
     while( number >0)
    {
        reverse = reverse * 10;
        reverse = reverse + number%10;
        number = number/10;
    }
    return reverse;
}
```

hope this helps!

Good luck!

Comment: What if there are more than 5 user inputs and then we have to reverse them. If we follow the above process the while loops will increase that is the overheads will increase and it will be tedious process.

Comment: @Roshan create a function which will return the reverse of number , In main programme use for-loop for 10 iterations and keep adding the value of reverse number from the new function in every iteration, in this way you can do for any number , 10 , 100, 10000 and so on

Answer (score 2):

1)Use while instead of if.

2) If you compute the reverse of second number inside the while loop that finds the reverse of first number, if second number is longer then it won't work. Do it separately

```
while(number > 0)
{
    reverse = reverse * 10;
    reverse = reverse + number%10;
    number = number/10;
}
while(num > 0)
{
    rev = rev * 10;
    rev = rev + num%10;
    num = num/10;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for guiding for internal details of while loop. And the program worked.

Comment: I have one more qestion.. What if I have to reverse more than 2 numbers and add it. Suppose 7 numbers to be reversed. So do we need to follow the same process or it can be code can be reduced to make it more efficient.

Comment: @Roshan create a function whihc will return the reverse of number ,
In main programme use for-loop for 10 iterations and keep adding the value of reverse number from the new function in every iteration, in this way you can do for any number , 10 , 100, 10000 and so on

Answer (score 0):

**You can do**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.StringBuilder
class HelloWorld
 {
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
  int n,n1, reverse = 0,rev = 0;
  String string1,string2;
  System.out.println("Enter the number to reverse");

  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.err.println("Please enter first number to reverse : ");
  int number = scanner.nextInt();

  System.out.println("Enter second number to reverse :");
  int num = scanner.nextInt();

  StringBuilder str1 =new StringBuilder(number+"");
  StringBuilder str2 =new StringBuilder(num+"");

   string1=str1.reverse().toString();
   string2=str2.reverse().toString();


 }
 System.out.println("Reverse of entered number is "+string1);
 System.out.println("Reverse of entered number is "+string2);
 }
}
```

At last you can conver the reversed string to integer using Integer.ParseInt method and add it

Comment: What if we have more than 5 inputs to be reversed and are to be added. Is there any other way to get 5 inputs simultaneoulsy and then reverse and add it.